# kendo Stock chart navigator format

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I have on kendo stock chart in my application.And here my navigator format is just like this jun '11.But i want to display to display the format like this "jun '11 to July '11".How to change that format of that navigator?Is it possible?Any body please help me....

```
        $("#stock-chart").kendoStockChart({
    dataSource: {
        data: chartData
    },
    series: [{
        name: "Line Data",
        type: "column",
        field: "lineData"
        },
        {
        name: "Column Data",
        type: "column",
        field: "columnData"
    }],
    categoryAxis: {
        baseUnit: "auto"
    },
    dateField: "Period",
    navigator: {
        series: {
            type: "area",
            field: "lineData"
        }
    }
});
```

My jsbin is http://jsbin.com/ocevot/5/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once try this one

```
categoryAxis: {
         labels:
      {      
    dateFormats: 
        {
          days: "MMM'dd"
    }
}
    }
```

Example fiddle http://jsbin.com/ocevot/14/edit